# Is this a correct reimplementation of Pytorch Seq2Seq model?

Tags: python, nlp, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, pytorch

I made a code that sort of change the tutorial script of seq2seq provided by Pytorch. Here’s the model:

```
class Seq2Seq(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, encoder, batch_size, vocab_size, input_size, output_size, hidden_dim, embedding_dim, n_layers=2, dropout_p=0.5):
    super(Seq2Seq, self).__init__()

    self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.input_length = input_size
    self.output_length = output_size
    self.vocab_size = vocab_size

    self.encoder = encoder
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout_p)
    self.selu = nn.SELU()
    self.decoder_embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, hidden_dim)
    self.decoder_gru = nn.GRU(hidden_dim, hidden_dim)
    self.out = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, vocab_size)
    self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax()

def decode(self, SOS_token, encoder_hidden, target_output, teacher_forcing_ratio=0.8):
    decoder_output_full = autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(self.output_length, self.batch_size, self.vocab_size))
    decoder_output_full = decoder_output_full.cuda() if use_cuda else decoder_output_full
    target = target_output.permute(1,0)

    use_teacher_forcing = True if random.random() < teacher_forcing_ratio else False

    for idx in range(self.output_length):
        if idx == 0:
            decoder_input = SOS_token
            decoder_hidden = encoder_hidden.unsqueeze(0)
        output = self.decoder_embeddings(decoder_input).view(1, self.batch_size, -1)
        output = self.dropout(output)

        output = self.selu(output)

        if use_teacher_forcing:
            decoder_output, decoder_hidden = self.decoder_gru(output, decoder_hidden)
            temp = 1
            out = self.out(decoder_output[0])
            out = out + sample_gumbel(out.shape)
            decoder_output = F.softmax(out / temp, dim=1)
            # decoder_output = (self.decoder_embeddings.weight * decoder_output.unsqueeze(1)).sum(0).view(1, 1, -1)
            decoder_output_full[idx, :, :] = decoder_output
            decoder_input = target[idx-1]  # Teacher forcing

        else:
            decoder_output, decoder_hidden = self.decoder_gru(output, decoder_hidden)
            temp = 1
            out = self.out(decoder_output[0])
            out = out + sample_gumbel(out.shape)
            decoder_output = F.softmax(out / temp, dim=1)
            # decoder_output = (self.decoder_embeddings.weight * decoder_output.unsqueeze(1)).sum(0).view(1, 1, -1)
            topv, topi = decoder_output.data.topk(1)
            # print topi
            ni = topi
            # decoder_input_v = autograd.Variable(torch.LongTensor([[ni]]))
            decoder_input = autograd.Variable(ni)
            # decoder_input = decoder_input.cuda() if use_cuda else decoder_input
            # print decoder_input
            decoder_output_full[idx, :, :] = decoder_output

    decoder_output_full = decoder_output_full.permute(1,0,2)

    # gen_output = self.softmax(self.out(decoder_output_full))

    return decoder_output_full

def forward(self, input, target_output, teacher_forcing_ratio=0.8):
    encoder_feat, _ = self.encoder(input)

    SOS_token = np.zeros((self.batch_size,1), dtype=np.int32)
    SOS_token = torch.LongTensor(SOS_token.tolist())
    SOS_token = autograd.Variable(SOS_token)
    if use_cuda:
        SOS_token = SOS_token.cuda(gpu)

    gen_output = self.decode(SOS_token, encoder_feat, target_output, teacher_forcing_ratio)

    return gen_output

def initHidden(self):
    result = autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(1, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim))
    if use_cuda:
        return result.cuda()
    else:
        return result
```

The way I calculate the NLL loss is by creating one whole sequence of output first and compare it with the target output. Here’s the loss function:

```
class batchNLLLoss(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(batchNLLLoss, self).__init__()

def forward(self, synt, target, claim_length=20):
    loss_fn = nn.NLLLoss()

    loss = 0

    for i in range(synt.shape[0]):
        for j in range(claim_length):
            loss += loss_fn(synt[i][j].unsqueeze(0), target[i][j])

    return loss
```

The current problem is the loss value is really small and seems like the network learns nothing (the output is the same word repeated again and again). Any thought about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Every loss function in pytorch can handle batches by itself. No need to create you own class. `nn.NLLLoss()(predictied_sequence, target_sequence)` will do the job.

Comment: what do you think about the seq2seq implementation though? seems like there's something wrong there too